# I can't understand the formal definition of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, field-theory, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences

I've always intuitively understood this set in intuitive sense, as "all numbers on the number line". However, now I want to know the formal definition:

> Consider the set of rational numbers, $\mathbb{Q}$.
>
> For any two Cauchy sequences of rational numbers $X=⟨x_n⟩,Y=⟨y_n⟩$, define an equivalence relation between the two as:
>
> $X≡Y⟺∀ϵ>0:∃n∈ \mathbb{N}:∀i,j>n:|x_i−y_j|<ϵ$
>
> The real numbers are the set of all equivalence classes $[[⟨x_n⟩]]$ of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers.

Most importantly, how do we deduce the axioms of the real number field from this definition?

Comment: What, more concretely, are the axioms you want to confirm that this $\Bbb R$ fulfills?

Comment: As a side note, this is a construction of $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ by a completion of $(\mathbb{Q},|\cdot|)$. There is an alternative construction via the method of Dedekind cuts that might prove more intuitive, as it relies more on order.

Comment: @par It is not necessarily more intuitive. For instance, the definition of multiplication on $\Bbb R$ under the Dedekind cut construction is quite complicated compared to multiplication under the Cauchy sequence construction.

Comment: @Arthur and it's not necessarily less intuitive either:) For instance, the existence of the least upper bound of a bounded set is easier to prove using Dedekind cuts. It's like squeezing a bag of water: you can displace the complexity, but in each case you have to sweat some details.

Comment: I meant that it might prove to be more intuitive [to the author] :-)

Comment: @par: The problem with this is that in the general theory of metric spaces, the completion is defined *using* a pre-existing notion of $\Bbb R$. So while you are correct, it is the completion of $\Bbb Q$ with the absolute value distance, it is incorrect to say that before you already have $\Bbb R$ available.

Comment: In any case, the answer to "how do we deduce the axioms of the real number field from this definition?" is "by getting our hands dirty", and at some length that's surely too great for stackexchange. Searching "construction of reals from rationals" turns up many lecture notes, including one from MIT courseware which states, on p. 7 of 22: "[N]ow 
that we have well-defined operations, it behooves us to prove that $\Bbb R$, equipped with them, is a field. This is a long and laborious task, and we shall not really work through it here; the interested reader should be in a position to [do so]".